# How to find the maximum cost(bandwidth) in a graph(network)?

Tags: algorithm, networking

I have tried Dijkstra's algorithm to find maxim cost but I am stuck in that how to tackle with infinity problem. Kindly do share any precise algorithm for this task.

Comment: Perhaps you need `Maximum flow problem`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify Dijkstra's algorithm in order to find the longest path - than it's impossible (unless P = NP):
https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/17980/is-it-possible-to-modify-dijkstra-algorithm-in-order-to-get-the-longest-path